# Missing cursor in Tropico 5

Tags: mouse, tropico-5

In Tropico 5, I can see the cursor in the options screen, etc. But when I am actually playing the game, puff, it's gone. The cursor exists, it shows a reaction when it is pointed at something, but it's invisible. I can see the cursor in some game, but I won't be able to continue finishing my campaign this way.

Does anybody have any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Follow these steps:

1. When you start a game, there will be a dialog box. You can't open Menu with that dialog still open. You have to fight to close that dialog box. Try to figure out where is your cursor currently and point it to OK button.
2. Click ESC and you'd see Menu. Save your game.
3. Open the saved game.
4. Done! Please enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I went into Windows settings and toggled the cursor pointer trails. They were switched off but having switched them on, the game works!